# Getting the responseText from XMLHttpRequest-Object

Tags: javascript, c++, html, web-applications, cgi

I wrote a cgi-script with c++ to return the query-string back to the requesting ajax object.
I also write the query-string in a file in order to see if the cgi script works correctly.
But when I ask in the html document for the response Text to be shown in a messagebox i get a blank message.

here is my code:

js:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var XMLHttp;
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
XMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function getresponse () {
XMLHttp.open
("GET", "http://localhost/cgi-bin/AJAXTest?" + "fname=" +
document.getElementById('fname').value + "&sname=" + 
document.getElementById('sname').value,true);
XMLHttp.send(null);
}

XMLHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(XMLHttp.readyState == 4)
{
document.getElementById('response_area').innerHTML +=  XMLHttp.readyState;
var x= XMLHttp.responseText
alert(x)
} 
}
</script>

First Names(s)<input onkeydown = "javascript: getresponse ()" 
id="fname" name="name"> <br>

Surname<input onkeydown = "javascript: getresponse();" id="sname">

<div id = "response_area">

</div>
```

C++:

```
int main() {

QFile log("log.txt");
if(!log.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    return 1;
}
QTextStream outLog(&log);
QString QUERY_STRING= getenv("QUERY_STRING");

//if(QUERY_STRING!=NULL)
//{

    cout<<"Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
        <<"The Query String is: "
        << QUERY_STRING.toStdString()<< "\n";
    outLog<<"Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
          <<"The Query String is: "
          <<QUERY_STRING<<endl;

//}

return 0;
}
```

I'm happy about every advice what to do!

EDIT: the output to my logfile works just fine:

```
Content-type: text/plain

The Query String is: fname=hello&sname=world
```

I just noticed that if i open it with IE8 i get the query-string. But only on the first "keydown" after that IE does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem had nothing to do with the code...
I was testing my script on the local IIS7 and I opened the html-page with double-clicking on the file. But you have to open the webpage via browser (localhost/mypage.htm) because otherwise for the browser the html and the executable have different origins. which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to use `javascript:` in `on___` handler, just `onkeydown="getresponse();"` is enough;
2. IE>=7 supports `XMLHttpRequest` object, so directly checking if `XMLHttpRequest` exists is better than checking whether navigator is IE. Example:

   ```
   if(XMLHttpRequest) XMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   else if(window.ActiveXObject) XMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   ```
3. inside your `getresponse()` function, try to add below code at the beginning (before `open`):

   ```
   try{XMLHTTP.abort();}catch(e){}
   ```

   Because you're using a global object, you may want to "close" it before opening another connection.

---

**Edit**:

Some browser (maybe Firefox itself?) do not handle non-"text/xml" response very well in default state, so to ensure things and stuffs, try this:

```
function getresponse () {
  try{XMLHttp.abort();}catch(e){}
  XMLHttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/cgi-bin/AJAXTest?" + "fname=" +
    document.getElementById('fname').value + "&sname=" + 
    document.getElementById('sname').value,true);
  if(XMLHttp.overrideMimeType) XMLHttp.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
  XMLHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Input! I made the changes. But I still have the same problem. IE8 gives me the query-string back. but FF just opens a blank message box. Do you have any idea where this could come from?

Comment: @Sammy46 So is IE getting text on every key down now?

Comment: YES! it actually is getting text on every key down. But i really would like to know what is going wrong when i use FF(version 10.0.7 if this can help?)

Comment: OK, i tried that, but in FF it doesn't change anything, in IE i get an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method". I downloaded a FF addon (HTTP Fox) it displays all HTTP in/out and i get the error: "text/plain (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)". Any other ideas?  EDIT: and it also says: Error while loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)

Comment: @Sammy46 I'm not sure if IE8 supports `overrideMimeType()`, but fine, one can make an `if` for that; about you FF error, what URL exactly are you sending? In production, you should use something like `"?fname="+encodeURIComponent(fname.value)` when constructing URI.

Comment: again thank you for your time! I now also use the encodeURI function, but it doesn't seem like that was the problem. the URL is http://localhost/cgi-bin/AJAXTest?fname=hello&sname=world (i also got this out of HTTP Fox)

Comment: the comment hides the h t t p : / / which of course is in front of the URL I pasted

Comment: @Sammy46 I'm lost here. While FF v10 is quite old, your example seems simple enough for it to handle. Maybe the problem lies in some other place.

Comment: I found my problem (see my answer) but i really appreciate your effort and since I'm just getting started with Ajax I'm glad about your tips!